# Add 12 months to a Date in PHP

Tags: php, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

We have a "start date" echoed out in a WooCoomerce email like so:

```
<?php echo esc_html( date_i18n( wc_date_format(), $subscription->get_time( 'start', 'site' ) ) ); ?>
```

The output looks like this: **March 29, 2017**

How would I go about adding 12 months to this date and echoing it out in the email as an "end date"?

Thanks

Comment: What does this give you? `$subscription->get_time( 'start', 'site' )`? If you get a datetime object it has methods to modify the date

Comment: It gives me the date the customer placed the order through WooCommerce. E.G. March 29, 2017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first line just sets up a variable for clarity's sake. The second line adds one year to the time and assigns it to `$endDate`. Simply add `$endDate` to your `echo`.

```
$startDate = $subscription->get_time( 'start', 'site' );
$endDate = date("F-d-Y", strtotime(date("F-d-Y", strtotime($startgDate)) . " + 1 year"));
```

Comment: Thanks. This is just echoed January-01-1970 which isn't right. When i echoed "$startDate" it resulted in 1490861344.

Comment: Hi, I just had to use `esc_html( date_i18n( wc_date_format(), $subscription->get_time( 'start', 'site' ) ) );` in the `$startDate` variable so it became `$startDate = esc_html( date_i18n( wc_date_format(), $subscription->get_time( 'start', 'site' ) ) );`.
Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Glad you figured it out